# failing to devtools::install_github() from an enterprise github account

Tags: r, github, devtools

I am trying to install an R package from an enterprise github account

```
devtools::install_github(
  repo = "<owner>/<repo>",
  host = "github.<org_name>.com/api/v3/",
  auth_token = <my_github_pat>
)
```

I get this error message
`Error: Failed to install '<repo>' from GitHub: HTTP error 404. Not Found Did you spell the repo owner ('<owner>') and repo name ('<repo>') correctly? - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.`

I have the correct spellings, and I think that I must have the required permissions because it's actually my repo: I can push and pull from the repo just fine. I am doing the `install_github()` as a test case so colleagues can install my package, but I can't make sense of this error message.

Comment: It's been a while but I think this has come up and the path of the repo is different under GHE -- so even if you square the pat away it won't "just work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally just needed to drop the last "/" in the host string and this worked. SMH

```
devtools::install_github(
  repo = "<owner>/<repo>",
  host = "github.<org_name>.com/api/v3",
  auth_token = <my_github_pat>
)
```

Comment: Nice, so then it was just the host= argument that takes care of the changed path.